# I search for newspaper articles to save them on a wiki site. What is the word for this "occupation?"

Tags: articles

For example: The site is for mass murder related articles. I occasionally search for the newspaper murder articles to write about them and keep them stored in the site. I had made numerous articles for the site. What is the name of this "occupation?"

Comment: What is wrong with this Q? Why all the **silent** down votes?

Comment: @Kris - I think it was the ad for his web site.

Comment: Well, it is my first question here, so i didn't know that you can't link sites. Sorry.

Comment: @Kris - I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 1):

**An amateur archivist**.

[archivist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/archivist)

> A person who maintains and is in charge of archives.

See also:
[Archivist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivist) on Wikipedia

This may interest you:
Panayotis Vryonis, "[an amateur digital archivist’s thoughts](https://blog.vrypan.net/2013/03/28/me-the-amature-archivist/)"